# Asp.net Menu Control - Dynamic menus show on page load

Tags: asp.net, aspmenu

I have an Asp.Net Menu control that displays across the top of our page. When the page is loaded, all the dymanic menus (the ones that fly out on mouseover) display until the page finishes loading, and then hide. Once the page finishes loading, they hide and behave as they should, but they are displayed until loading is complete.

Anyone have any suggestions on why this is happening or how to get it to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the menu with your css `display:none` and then use jquery to display it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(yourclass/idhere).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Successfully used the following: $(document).ready(function() { $('#" & myMenu.ClientID & "').show(); });

Answer (score 1):

dont use asp.net ready to use controls, u dont know the code they produce. As a web developer u have to knoq exaclty what ll be the code at the page.

As for answer, you may hide your menu by adding display:none style to your menu, and in javascript write a code to show it after page loads.